# JAX-RS ignores bean validation constraints

Tags: validation, jax-rs

I made a JAX-RS service. It consumes/produces json via POST requests. Everything works fine except bean validation

I added some constraints from package `javax.validation.constraints` to the fields of my POJOs, that are used as wrappers for request/response messages.
(POJOs does not have any other annotations like JAXB @XmlRootElement or smth else)

If I try to call my service - it works, but constraints ignored completely. I.e. I call my service using right or wrong parameters and calls passed RAX-RS layer to my EJB in both cases.

What could I miss? Some special config, some special dependencies?

P.S. I use glassfish 4.0 with provided Jersey 2.0

Answer (score 1):

In order for bean validation to be invoked you need to have a validator on your classpath.  A commonly used validator is the `hibernate-validator` as it is the reference implementation.

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

Once you have the validator on the classpath it will be detected and invoked when JSR-303 annotations are encountered.